# use custom XSD in Crystal Reports 2016

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, crystal-reports, xsi

I am trying to export data from crystal reports in XML format but problem is data is enclosed in tags like `Formatted Value` and `Value` but my requirement is to get user specific tags. For E.g

If my data has Employee name and Employee ID then I need as below:

```
<Employee Name> abc </Employee Name>
<Employee ID> 123 </Employee ID>
```

But XML export from crystal is like below

```
<Formatted Value> abc </Formatted Value>
<Formatted Value> 123 </Formatted Value>
```

Tried different ways to change the default XSD created by Crystal Reports but unfortunately couldn't get needed.

Any idea or stating point to get the solution would be really helpful, trying for couple of days for now without any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options are:

1. export to TEXT format and take care of tags yourself.
2. export to XML and, in the resulting file, replace the tags. At least one of the 3rd-party tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) can automate the process of exporting and immediately replacing the bad tags with good tags based on replacement pairs you specify.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I don't think second point is accepted, but first point is a very valid point. Will accept tomorrow